# What is a better way to say "computer person with a lot of experience in multiple parts of computer-related areas"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I am trying to create a concise 'title' for my experience working in the computer field.

I have experience in multiple programming languages and multiple roles (manager, technician, programmer) and multiple applications (most mainframe based) and I have been at this for quite some time. But all I can come up with is this:

> Well rounded computer systems specialist

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit informal but you may say "computer guru" or may be "computer veteran" to put a stress on experience.

Answer (score 1):

For any kind of "formal" context, I doubt terms like *computer guru/veteran* would be suitable.

Assuming OP particularly wishes to convey the three specific areas in which he has extensive experience, perhaps...

> I have experience across a broad range of languages, applications, and team roles.

Personally, I'd be inclined to add *(up to and including managing teams)*, because many people might assume *team roles* only goes up to *team leader* at best - and I personally would say that's a considerable step below *manager*.

Answer (score 1):

*computer savvy* 
would be my best bet for an informal term.

```
savvy
noun

: practical understanding or knowledge of something
```

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/savvy

However for something like a CV or title of profession;
*computer specialist*
would cover general areas of computing without being too informal or 'pop'.

But, I'd say you're much better off listing actual areas experiences rather than trying to coin a single term.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some titles I have found people using:

Computer - Guru

Techno - Polymath

Computer - Polymath

Multi-Speciality Computer Expert

Comment: "Multi-Speciality" is definitely an oxymoron in my book. In a resume or cover letter I'd raise my eyebrows on seeing that.